# Facing problem in Netbeans 6.5

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.5

I am using Netbeans 6.5 IDE. In the IDE, errors and warnings are highlighted as and when code is being written.
I recently installed a plugin and since then, none of the errors are being highlighted in any code that I type in. Only after I build a project do I get to know about all the errors.
The plugin I installed may have deactivated the automatic highlighting of errors.
How do I fix it?? I tried deactivating the plugin, but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible Solution is to reset your IDE. But remember it will delet all your custom settings.

Here is an useful Link:
http://blogs.oracle.com/NetBeansSupport/entry/resetting_the_netbeans_userdir

As i stated in pixelines answer i would suggest you to do an Update. Netbeans Plugins are working more efficient now.

Comment: sounds like it is in really bad state. I hope you use SVN or something like that. Uninstall and install new Netbeans 6.7. I am sorry...

Answer (score 1):

did you try upgrading to netbeans 6.7.1 ?

Comment: +1 Updating your IDE. A lot of plugins are working smoother now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to Java, but with the C/C++ plugin it's possible to switch this highlighting on/off via **Options** -> **C/C++** -> **Highlighting**